# C++: pass typedef struct pointer to function, get ambiguous errors

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

The code passes `typedef struct` by pointer, but error happened

The code:

define the `typedef struct`

```
typedef struct MemBuffer
{  
  unsigned    char *buffer;  
  unsigned    char *position;  
  size_t      size;  
} MemBuffer;  
  ...
```

the class head file

```
class Request
{
private:
  void MemBufferGrow(MemBuffer *b)
  void MemBufferAddByte(MemBuffer *b, unsigned char byt);  
  ...
}
```

the class `.cpp` file

```
void Request::MemBufferGrow(MemBuffer *b)  
{  
  size_t sz;  
  sz = b->position - b->buffer;  
  b->size = b->size *2;  
  b->buffer =(unsigned    char *) realloc(b->buffer,b->size);  
  b->position = b->buffer + sz;    
}  

void Request::MemBufferAddByte(MemBuffer  *b,unsigned char byt)
{  
  if( (size_t)(b->position-b->buffer) >= b->size )  
    MemBufferGrow(b);  //at this line, I get that ambiguous error

  *(b->position++) = byt;  
}
```

inside the function:

```
void Request::MemBufferAddByte(MemBuffer  *b,unsigned char byt)
```

when `MemBufferGrow(b)` is called, the error happened,

'MemBufferGrow' is ambiguous ' Candidates are: void MemBufferGrow(MemBuffer *) '

Comment: Stop. Using. Typedef struct.

Comment: struct T {}; implies typedef struct T {} T; in C++

Comment: If a name is ambiguous then the compiler usually shows at least two candidates for the name. So show the complete set of error mesaages.

Comment: The code is incomplete, does not compile and is not a valid test case. Even a second 'MemBufferGrow' is missing!

Comment: void MeMBufferGrow(MemBuffer *b) is not the same with void Request::MemBufferGrow(MemBuffer *b), see big 'M' in the declaration.

Comment: @neagoegab   'void MeMBufferGrow(MemBuffer *b)' is a typo, corrected

Comment: Great, struct T{} solved that error. Thanks @ScarletAmaranth

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, that's already the complete error message

Answer (score 0):

so to slove this problem in C++.

```
typedef struct MemBuffer
{  
  unsigned    char *buffer;  
  unsigned    char *position;  
  size_t      size;  
} MemBuffer;
```

should be corrected as:

```
struct MemBuffer
{  
  unsigned    char *buffer;  
  unsigned    char *position;  
  size_t      size;  
};
```

In C++, we should use `struct T{ ... }` instead of `typedef struct { ... }T`

The first case actually runs without error in VC++.

But it does report error in g++ compiler (which I use cygwin eclipse C++).